# Exception: Failed to send email: No recipient, No idea what's wrong

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So basically, my WebApp working fine till yesterday. Suddenly giving this error today. Still sending emails to all the populated cells, and after sending it is giving this error in last.
I code this

```
function sendMailfj() {
  var first = 0;
  var last = 1;
  var email = 2;
  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
  //Logger.log(aliases[2]);

  var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("emailfj");

  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FJ");

  var data = ws.getRange("A2:C" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();

  data.forEach(function(row){
    emailTemp.fn = row[first];
    emailTemp.ln = row[last];
    var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
    GmailApp.sendEmail(
      row[email], 
      "Your Recent Shopping Experience with XYZ Jackets", 
      "Your email doesn't support HTML",
      {'from':aliases[2], name: "XYZ Jackets", htmlBody: htmlMessage}
      );

  });

}
```

any help would be highly appreciated
[image: Screenshot]

console.log(row[email]) inside data.forEach() is
[image]

The email is right, and my app can send an email to this address or any other in raw if any available. but after sending an email, the error generates

and after a while, this happens
[image: error at the end of debugging]

Sorry I am no good with JS

Comment: there is an obvious issue with `row[email]`. Why don't you simply check what the value of that variable is before the error occurs? For example, put `console.log(row[email])` inside `data.forEach` and see the execution log for the messages. Then edit your question here to include that info as well.

Comment: hmm you are getting two different errors? the last screenshot shows that your code does not manage to finish within the quota time of (6 or 30 minutes). It is not about JS. Your code is pretty much optimal. The issue has to do with the volume of emails you want to send.

Comment: email volume is just 4 to 5 email per day. as per Google our account is eligible to send 100 email aday

Comment: only one error.

Comment: If you see in the last screenshot you shared your script took more than 6 minutes to execute. It started at 2:22:57 and interrupted at 2:28:57 after 6 minutes. It is not about the email quota here, it is about the time quota restriction of 6 minutes. How many rows do you have ? What do you think it delays the process ? Because if you send only 5 emails in 6 minutes it means that per email the script takes 1 minute which I can't understand why based on your code.

Comment: I figured it out. It is happening due to getLastRow(). I unwillingly put some text in column H while columns A, B, and C are empty. I removed the text, and scripts start behaving normally

Comment: I posted an alternative solution to make sure unwanted filled rows does not destroy your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment the issue was some random value was filled in and `getLastRow` was returning the wrong row.

You can determine the last row based on your email column like that:

```
function sendMailfj() {
  var first = 0;
  var last = 1;
  var email = 2;
  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
  //Logger.log(aliases[2]);

  var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("emailfj");

  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FJ");

  var Clast = ws.getRange("C1:C").getValues().filter(String).length; // new code
  
  var data = ws.getRange("A2:C" + Clast).getValues(); // modified code

  data.forEach(function(row){
    emailTemp.fn = row[first];
    emailTemp.ln = row[last];
    var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
    GmailApp.sendEmail(
      row[email], 
      "Your Recent Shopping Experience with XYZ Jackets", 
      "Your email doesn't support HTML",
      {'from':aliases[2], name: "XYZ Jackets", htmlBody: htmlMessage}
      );

  });

}
```